# Any Ideas to Optimize the ASP.Net Server Load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, visual-studio-2008

I am developing using `VSTS 2008` + `C#` + `.Net 3.5` to develop an `ASP.Net` application. At the client side, in order to keep the session live, I will refresh the server every 5 seconds. Here is my code at the client side, server side Default.aspx will do nothing -- the only purpose is to keep client alive.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
<iframe src="http://localhost:20000/Default.aspx" width="1" height="1" />
</head>
<body />
<html>
```

I have monitored the traffic and found each time that the client will send a couple of headers to the server side. Any ideas to reduce the server load or traffic? If the number of clients are big, I am afraid the server workload will be increased significantly.

Here is the request and response header I monitored,

Request headers

> Connection : Keep-Alive Accept : */* Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language : en-us Host : localhost:20000 User-Agent :
>   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1;
>   .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.21022;
>   CIBA; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 3.0.30729;
>   OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)

Response headers

> Server : Microsoft-IIS/7.0

Comment: The `<iframe/>` element is invalid inside `<head/>`.

Answer (score 2):

First question is: Why on earth do you think you have to keep the client alive?? What's the purpose of that??

Marc

Comment: Hi Marc, I am keeping a very short session live timeout because the web application contains some important data and I want to avoid issues when user forget to logout, and another hacker comes to use his/her computer to use previous user's session information to do some hacking things.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to keep the session alive manually anyways you'll end up with those same problems and the kind of problems you're now trying to solve.

If you really really wanna try and make your application harder to hack based on session information (which most web banks see no reason to do other than to force a locout after like 10 min) you could reverse the logic. Have the server notify the client that the session will be terminated if the client replies the termination can be cancelled. (this can be done in JavaScript client side so if the browser has been closed there'll be no reply)

Comment: Thanks Rune, 1. another related question, how to set Session Timeout shorter than 1 minute? I found Session.Timeout property could only set session timeout in the basis of minute, so I can only set 1 minute as the minimal itme. 2. I would like to follow your points to implement Java script based solution, any reference code?

Comment: @George for the JavaScript part what you'd have to do is to make a call from the web page to the server, that call needs to have a long timeout. When the server needs to terminate it will then reply to the request sent from the page when it loaded

Comment: But I do really suggest to rethink if it's really worth the trouble even web banks don't go that far to protect them self from session hijacking due to some one not logging out.

Comment: @George2: You can't set the session timeout shorter than one minute.

Comment: Hi Guffa, I am surprised to learn that. :-)

Do you have any documents to prove it?